# question re terraform and github actions / secrets

Tags: terraform, github-actions

I am starting to learn terraform/github actions.  Is it possible to get TF to read Github secrets as part of the Github action ? For example ..

My main.tf file creates an AWS EC2 instance, and, needs to install nginx using a provisioner.  in order to do that i need to provide my private/public key information to the provisoner for it to authentiate to the EC2 instance to install the app. I have created a github secret that contains my private key.

At the moment the workflow keeps failing becuase i cannot get it to read the github secret that contains the private key info.

How can i achieve this ?

any advise would be most welcome !  thanks

Comment: Have you read https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/encrypted-secrets? Is there something specific there that you've tried that doesn't work? If so can you edit the question to show what you've tried and what error you get please?

Comment: If the action is calling Terraform, can you instead pass the secrets to Terraform?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The simplest way is to use an environment variable.

Terraform reads the value for its [variables from environment](https://www.terraform.io/docs/commands/environment-variables.html#tf_var_name).
The next piece is to translate the [GitHub secret in an environment variable](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#jobsjob_idstepsenv).

In practice, if your Terraform script has a variable declaration like

```
variable "my_public_key" {}
```

and you have a GitHub secret *NGINX_PUBKEY*, then you can use this syntax in your workflow

```yaml
steps:
  - run: terraform apply -auto-approve
    env:
      TF_VAR_my_public_key: ${{ secrets.NGINX_PUBKEY }}
```

This said I would not recommend using GitHub secrets for this kind of data: they are better managed in a secret-management store like AWS Secrets Manager, Azure KeyVault, Hashicorp Vault, etc.

Comment: I require to use cloud credentials like aws secret key or access key. Is github good place to store that? Since I would be running my terraform script form there and for creation of resources it would need cloud creds.

Comment: Yours is worth an S.O. question in itself; shortly it depends. How important are those credentials, how many permissions the account have etc. For an hobbyist project GH secrets are fine, for an enterprise application, I would say not (too long to explain here). Hope this helps

Comment: @GiulioVian what if one wants to create Secrets through Terraform? So the secrets are initially added to GitHub secrets, and then the value is read by Terraform and deployed to AWS Secrets Manager. The benefit is - IaC is used for resource provisioning.